# Angular: Can't bind to 'uploader' but FileUploadModule is imported in same module

Tags: angular, file-upload, ng2-file-upload

I've got a strange problem while using the [uploader] file drop directive from ng2-file-upload. The Angular complier output is:

> Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

I searched for any similar Problems on this site, but from my perspective, everything is correct:

- Declare Component in app.module - check
- Import FileUploaderModule in the same app.module - check
- no other modules (besides routing)

the app.module:

```
[...]
import { SongFilesComponent } from './components/songs/song-files/song-files.component';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    [...]
    SongFilesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    [...]
    FileUploadModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

SongFilesComponent:

```
[...]
<div
  [uploader]="newFileUploader"
  (fileOver)="onFileOverNew($event)"
  [class.file-over]="fileOverNew"
>
  Drop file here
</div>
[...]
```

But I always get the described error.
I have a second simple test project and the the uploader works. But I can't find any difference between them two.

The whole project is hosted on https://github.com/smuddy/wgenerator/tree/master/WEB

Comment: replace `<div>`by the real name of your component

Comment: ok sorry, I added the SongFilesComponent in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the component selector that you're trying to use (DIV element is not an angular component, and has not any `uploader` Input).

You need to replace :

```
[...]
<div
  [uploader]="newFileUploader"
  (fileOver)="onFileOverNew($event)"
  [class.file-over]="fileOverNew"
>
  Drop file here
</div>
[...]
```

by

```
[...]
<div ng2FileDrop
  [uploader]="newFileUploader"
  (fileOver)="onFileOverNew($event)"
  [class.file-over]="fileOverNew"
>
  Drop file here
</div>
[...]
```